# Changing "Product [product:title] added to your cart." message in Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce, rules

I'm trying to change/customize this message and have found that it is generated by "Display an Add to Cart message" rule from Drupal Rules. Everything would be fine but I can't find this text and I also don't know what to alter (and how) to change this message. Does anyone tried to do this?

Comment: I also have this problem :(

Comment: commerce_cart.rules.inc -> function commerce_cart_rules_add_to_cart_message($product) didn't help you?

Comment: @xurshid29 ,patching module is not clear way :(

Answer (score 3):

There are several Options,

1. got to rules and disable the add to cart rule, then create your own.
2. Use this module https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides to override the string. The string to override is this "%title added to your cart."

I wouldn't edit the module file commerce_cart.rules.inc -> function commerce_cart_rules_add_to_cart_message($product) as when you update it will just overwrite what you have done

Comment: as I wrote it is not a good solution but i couldn't find another one. And I don't think that stringoverride supports wildcards.

Comment: actually a good thread here about it http://www.drupalcommerce.org/discussions/669/change-cart-basket

Comment: I mean, drupal_set_title() in commerce_cart_rules_add_to_cart_message($product) gets a $product object as argument, and it can be different product objects and different titles. That's why module string overrides can't handle the $product objects and titles, I think.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is with: `hook_rules_action_info_alter()`

```
function HOOK_rules_action_info_alter(&$actions) {
    $actions['commerce_cart_add_to_cart_message']['callbacks']['execute'] = 'MODULE_custom_cart_callback';
}

function MODULE_custom_cart_callback($product) {
    drupal_set_message(t('%title added to <a href="!cart-url">your cart</a>.', array('%title' => $product->title, '!cart-url' => url('cart'))));
}
```

Basic steps:

1. Create a new module.
2. Add the `hook_rules_action_info_alter()` hook replacing "HOOK" with your module name.
3. Define `MODULE_custom_cart_callback($product)` replacing "MODULE" with your module name.
4. Enable the module and clear the cache.

Comment: Just edit the rule via the UI, no need to override the callback.

Comment: True, you could delete the show cart action and use the System action for "Show a message on the site". However I'd prefer to manage it in code, less chance of something getting reverted and trackable in git. Also, with above you'd override any other places that same action is used, eg a quick add to cart module may re-use that same action.

Comment: But it would lead to frustration if the user tried to change it from the UI and it didn't work (as it would be overriden by the alter hook). Could it be made to work with [hook_default_rules_configuration](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21rules%21rules.api.php/function/hook_default_rules_configuration_alter/7)?

Comment: You can't customise the message from the UI and the code above only changes the function used to display the message. So I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Definitely the best answer. Disabling and cloning rules is a bit of a ball-ache when you're doing everything with features. I needed a custom implementation because I want to suppress the drupal_set_message and instead pop the cart block out, so this worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am using this to replace an existing drupal message to my custom message.

```
function _exclude_message($mymessage, $mytype="status"){    $flag = false if ($messageArr = drupal_set_message()) {  foreach($messageArr as $type=>$messages) {
  if ($mytype==$type) {
    foreach($messages as $key=>$message) {
      if ($mymessage==$message) {
    unset($_SESSION['messages'][$type][intval($key)]);
       $flag = true;
      }
   }
  }

  if (count($_SESSION['messages'][$type])==0) unset($_SESSION['messages'][$type]);}} return $flag;}
function my_theme_status_messages($display = NULL) {
  if (_exclude_message('Sorry, unrecognized username or password. <a href="/user/password">Have you forgotten your password?</a>',"error")) drupal_set_message("Sorry, unrecognized username or password.","error");
 return theme_status_messages($display);
}
```

under template.php

this code will replace existing "Sorry, unrecognized username or password.Have you forgotten your password?" with my custom message "Sorry, unrecognized username or password.".

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using String Overrides module and there was no need to delete the message rule. I found the message rule defined in the commerce cart module code

**%title added to your cart.**
so just changed it, for example, to 
**%title added to your basket.**

...where as the other message was configured
**%title removed from your cart.**
and needed changing to, for example
**%title removed from your basket.**

Hope that would be helpful :)